# XSLT process all nodes untill reach a node with specific name

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml structure:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
    <item/>
    <desc/>
    <desc2/>
    <desc3/>
    <price1/>
    <info/>
    <info/>
    <info2/>
    <item/>
    <desc/>
    <price1/>
    <price2/>
    <price3/>
    <info1/>
    <anotheriinfo/>
    <specialinfo/>
    <item/>
    <desc/>
    <price1/>
</items>
```

Where `<item>` is not parent to the following nodes.
I need to group the different items with the corresponding information and pricing. Is there a way to select `<item>` and all following nodes just before the next `<item>` and to apply some logig ? Or to group them like

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <desc/>
    <desc2/>
    <desc3/>
    <price1/>
    <info/>
    <info/>
    <info2/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <desc/>
    <price1/>
    <price2/>
    <price3/>
    <info1/>
    <anotheriinfo/>
    <specialinfo/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <desc/>
    <price1/>
  </item>
</items>
```

I need to use XSLT 1.0

Comment: To clearly show your input structure, you should add end tags. As for grouping the sibling elements if I understand that correctly, look into XSLT 2 or 3 and `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="item">`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MartinHonnen ! But i need to use XSLT 1.0. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Sperberg-McQueens solution with Muenchian grouping. I pursued a completely different approach (again!!) based on `position()` and the number of following siblings that produces the desired result as well. Just wanted to share this:

```
<xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- total number of items -->
        <xsl:variable name="countItems" select="count(item)"/>
        <!-- edit: copy elements before first item -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[following-sibling::item[$countItems]]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="item">
            <!-- position of current item -->
            <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="following-sibling::item">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <!-- get all elements before next item -->
                        <!-- = all elements followed by (total items minus current position) items -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[following-sibling::item[$countItems - $position]]"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. My solution could be questionable in terms of "good xslt understanding", but personally I learn a lot from comparing solutions to each other, so I shared it. I appreciate when it is of any use.

Comment: One more question :) And what if i have another nodes above the first *<item>* and i want just to copy them just as they are (without moving or modifying them) and to keep the current logic (for all *<item>* nodes and all nodes below them) ?

Comment: You can do with the same logic, just insert `<xsl:copy-of select="*[following-sibling::item[$countItems]]"/>` right before `for-each`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Three techniques you might want to read up on and apply here.

- If all you want is a blank line before the display of an `item` element (as suggested by "Or to group them like ..."), write your stylesheet to emit that.
- Read up on Muenchian grouping; the value to group on is the number of preceding siblings named `item` (for nodes not themselves named `item`) or the number of preceding siblings named `item` plus one (for `item` elements).
- Learn to perform a tree traversal by having a template call `apply-templates` first on its children and then on its immediate right sibling.  In this case, the basic pattern is

  ```
  <xsl:template match="items">
    <xsl:apply-templates match="item"/>
  </

  <xsl:template match="item">  
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- handle descendants, if your current items have any ... --> 
      <xsl:apply-templates match="@*|node()"/>
      <!-- bring right siblings into the content ... -->
      <xsl:apply-templates match="following-sibling::*[1]" 
           mode="group-nodes"/>
    </
  </

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="group-nodes" priority="1">
    <!-- 1 handle this element -->
    <!-- modify next line if items elements can nest ... -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>

    <!-- 2 handle next sibling -->
    <xsl:apply-templates match="following-sibling::*[1]" 
           mode="group-nodes"/>
    </
  </

  <xsl:template match="item" mode="group-nodes" priority="10"/>
  ```